# Parsing List or dict to Flask from Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, flask, beautifulsoup

i am new to python, flask and beautiful soup in general.
So here is the deal. I am scraping some data from web with Beautifulsoup.

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import requests

    # PageURL's configure
    mainpage = 'http://www.myauto.ge/'
    pageurl = 'http://www.myauto.ge/?action=search&page='
    pagenum = 0

    # Looping Pages. Seems Wrong but doing its job?
    for x in range(0, 2):
        pagenum += 1
        r = requests.get(pageurl + str(pagenum))
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

        for cars in soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'car-info-wrapper'}):

            cname = cars.find("div", {"class": "car-name-wrapper"}).find('a').get_text()
            cyear = cars.find("p", {"class": "cr-levy car-year"}).get_text()
            ceng = cars.find("div", {"class": "cr-det-in cr-engine"}).p.get_text()
            cengroad = cars.find("div", {"class": "cr-det-in cr-road"}).p.get_text()
            # clink = cars.find('a').get('href')
```

when i print cname, cyear, ceng and cengroad its doing its job perfect like i want it. but now i am trying to do this in flask. instead of creating database in sqlite3 , i want it to simple scrape data and parse it to index.html.

this is my app.py flask code.

```
# Import
from flask import Flask, render_template
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


app = Flask(__name__)

# mainpage = 'http://www.myauto.ge/'
pageurl = 'http://www.myauto.ge/?action=search&page='
# pagenum = 0



# Our index
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    # for x in range(0, 2):
    #     pagenum += 1
    r = requests.get(pageurl)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

    data = []
    for cars in soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'car-info-wrapper'}):
        cname = cars.find("div", {"class": "car-name-wrapper"}).find('a').get_text()

        data.append(cname)

    datayear =[]
    for cars in soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'car-info-wrapper'}):   
        cyear = cars.find("p", {"class": "cr-levy car-year"}).get_text()
        datayear.append(cyear)


    return render_template("index.html", data=data,datayear=datayear)




if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

this is  my index.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block body %}
<table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Car</th>
        <th>Year</th>
        <th>Engine</th>
        <th>Road so far</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

   <tr>
     <td> {{ data }} </td>
     <td> {{ datayear }} </td>
   </tr>


    </tbody>
  </table>

{% endblock %}
```

[and this is what i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvNvh.png)

if try to

```
  <tr>
   {% for x in data %}
     <td> {{ x }} </td>
     <td>         </td>
   </tr>
```

[I get what i want but only for Car name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snVsp.png)

so how to do it with Car year the same

```
   <tr>
   {% for x in data %}
     <td> {{ carname }} </td>
     <td> {{ caryear }} </td>
   </tr>
```

or do something like this and then split list?

```
data = []
for cars in soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'car-info-wrapper'}):
    cname = cars.find("div", {"class": "car-name-wrapper"}).find('a').get_text()
    cyear = cars.find("p", {"class": "cr-levy car-year"}).get_text()

    data.append(cname)
    data.append(cyear)
```

or should i try it without list and dict? i just dont want use db.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Do you know how to make classes in Python?

Comment: no :( but i am learning the hard way :)

Comment: Like literally "learn python the hard way"? There's somewhere on this site that lists all the things wrong with those guides

Comment: @cricket_007 some times there are some ideas in my head. like this one. Scrape web and parse data to flask.  and i am on beginner level of python and almost zero level at flask. then i code and learn it the hard way :) that what i meant by saying " but i am learning the hard way" :))

Comment: Gotcha. I assumed you meant this http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/

Comment: @cricket_007: FWIW, the list you're thinking about is [LPTHW Complaints](http://sopython.com/wiki/LPTHW_Complaints). If there are other things you like to add to that list please let us know in the SO Python Chat room.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there, but instead of looping twice in your view code, just loop once and create a dictionary of the car data and add that to your list, like this:

```
data = []
for cars in soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'car-info-wrapper'}):
    car_info = {} # Start with an empty dictionary for each car.

    car_info['name'] = cars.find("div", {"class": "car-name-wrapper"}).find('a').get_text()
    car_info['year'] = cars.find("p", {"class": "cr-levy car-year"}).get_text()
    car_info['engine'] = cars.find("div", {"class": "cr-det-in cr-engine"}).p.get_text()
    car_info['mileage'] = cars.find("div", {"class": "cr-det-in cr-road"}).p.get_text()

    data.append(car_info)

return render_template("index.html", data=data)
```

Then in your template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block body %}
<table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Car</th>
        <th>Year</th>
        <th>Engine</th>
        <th>Road so far</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

   {% for car_info in data %}
   <tr>
     <td> {{ car_info['name'] }} </td>
     <td> {{ car_info['year'] }} </td>
     <td> {{ car_info['engine'] }} </td>
     <td> {{ car_info['mileage'] }} </td>
   </tr>
   {% endfor %}

    </tbody>
  </table>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Thanks you @Burhan Khalid , That solved my problem and did what i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

That second approach should work, but you'll want to group the data together in some way.

For example, instead of two lines, try to put them in a tuple.

```
data.append((came, cyear))
```

Then in your template, you can extract out those values.

```
{% for x in data %}
<tr>
  <td> {{ x[0] }} </td>
  <td> {{ x[1] }} </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Using a dictionary or object class for a Car would be the better, more verbose approach, but that should work for this simple example